# How can I get access to google calendar inside electron-react-boilerplate app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, google-calendar-api

I'm using Electron React Boilerplate to make a simple desktop app. i need to get access to google calendar to fetch all the events related to any gmail account.
i used "gapi-script" library to connnect with gogle and fetch the events.
i created two idClient OAuth one of them desktop application type and the other web application,
whenever i used desktop type i shows an error says:
[Storagerelay URI is not allowed for 'NATIVE_DESKTOP' client type.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkFZo.png)
if i used the idClient of web application it connect but i could not get the result coz it redirect to the browser and didn't go back to the app:
[popup blocked by browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7wIc.png)

this is my code here:
`

```
function handleAuthClick() {
   gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
}
function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.load('client', () => {
  gapi.client.init({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
    scope: SCOPES
  }).then(() => {
     gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
     updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
   });
 });
}

const updateSigninStatus = (isSignedIn: any) => {
  if (isSignedIn) {
    listUpcomingEvents();
  }
};

const listUpcomingEvents = () => {
  gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
    'calendarId': 'primary',
    'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
    'showDeleted': false,
    'singleEvents': true,
    'maxResults': 10,
    'orderBy': 'startTime',
  }).then((response: any) => {
    setEventss(response.result.items);
  });
};
```

`

Is there a way I can open a popup of access to google on the app? Or i need to send data from the browser back to the app?